# Adicionar um valor ao while em php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, while

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gibellino");
  mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from index_img");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $img = $row['img'];
    echo "<td><img src='../imagem/bd/index/$img' width='170px' height='300px'><a href='#'><img src='../imagem/fancy_closebox.png' id='fechar'></a></td>";
  }
}
?>
```

Bom, e queria que o **while** tivesse mais um valor que o numero de dados da base de dados.
Do género:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)+1)
```

já tentei por +1 no **while** já tentei criar o **row** fora do **while** e adicionar-lhe 1 mas da-me sempre erro.

Comment: Explique melhor que pretende fazer. Qual o resultado esperado.

Comment: @DanielOmine o numero "n" que o while tem vem da base de dados, certo? o que eu queria é que o numero que o while tivesse era "n+1". por exemplo tenho 5 dados na base de dados e queria que o while fosse buscar esses 5 dados e acrescenta-se um valor assim ficava 6

Comment: isso é óbvio.. o que pergunto é , por quê quer  mais 1 ?  é para poder gerar mais 1  `<td><img src='... ` ?  (off topic: por favor, procure escrever português corretamente)

Comment: sim é para poder gerar mais 1 <img> mas essa imagem não vem da mesma tabela.

Comment: então coloque essa imagem adicional fora do laço de repetição.

Comment: O problema é que eu tenho uma tabela com imagens (acho que isso já deu para ver) mas eu não sei quantas imagens tenho lá porque posso adicionar como remover imagens da tabela. E queria adicionar, quando o numero de imagens da base de dados chegasse ao fim, uma imagem diferente que não está na base de dados

Comment: Sinceramente eu ainda não entendi o objetivo. Edite sua pergunta e esclareça melhor.

Answer (score 2):

O valor que está sendo passado ao `while` não é um número `n` como você está pensando, por isso não é possível fazer o `+1` que você queria.

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

A variável `$row` da expressão está recebendo um *array* da função `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`, e desde que esse *array* não esteja vazio, o PHP vai interpretar como verdadeira `TRUE` e quando os dados terminarem a expressão vai retornar `NULL` que será interpretado como `FALSE` e então o *while* será interrompido.

Observe o seguinte código:

```
while(TRUE) {
   // Trecho de código
}
```

O código acima representa um *loop* (laço de repetição) **infinito**, ou seja "nunca" será interrompido, a não ser que seja adicionado um `break` dentro do *loop*.

Porém existe uma forma de fazer da maneira que você queria, basta usar um contador em vez da expressão `$row = ...`, exemplo:

```
$nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($nrows){
   $nrows--;
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   // Restante do código aqui
}
```

Porém o problema é que quando finalizar a contagem, onde possui `$row['img']` será lançado um erro de index, pois a variável `$row` terá o valor `NULL`, já que terminou os dados. Para contornar isso teria que adicionar alguns *if's* e/ou operações ternárias, coisas totalmente desnecessárias se colocar a imagem padrão após o *loop* como no exemplo:

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gibellino");
  mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from index_img");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $img = $row['img'];
    echo "<td><img src='../imagem/bd/index/$img' width='170px' height='300px'><a href='#'><img src='../imagem/fancy_closebox.png' id='fechar'></a></td>";
  }

  // Aqui fora do loop vai a imagem padrão que será sempre adicionada após todas as demais.
  echo "<td><img src='../imagem/bd/index/aqui-vai-a-imagem-padrao.jpg' width='170px' height='300px'><a href='#'><img src='../imagem/fancy_closebox.png' id='fechar'></a></td>";
}
?>
```